# ¿Como puedo traer el nombre de una tabla a través del ID en Ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net, mvc, razor, tablas

estoy trabajando con una vista razor en asp.Net y mvc c#, tengo mi ajax donde estoy mostrando una lista de datos desde la base de datos y pues no se de que manera en el campo id quisiera que me mostrara el nombre de la tabla ya que es una foranea

```
<script>
function Lista() {
    var table = $("#lista_users");
    var dato = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Lista", "Usuarios")",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            table.empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                if (data) {
                    dato += "<tr>";
                    dato += "<td>" + val.usuario + "</td>";
                    dato += "<td>" + val.nombre + "</td>";
                    dato += "<td>" + val.apellido + "</td>";
                    dato += "<td>" + val.id_rol + "</td>";
                    dato += "</tr>";
                }
            });
            table.append(dato);
            jQuery("#dialogo").dialog("close");
        },
    });
}
```

ese campo id_rol me enlaza a la tabla padre roles y quisiera mostrar el nombre de ese rol en vez del id en mi vista, si alguien puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho.

mi json es así

```
public JsonResult Lista() {
        return Json(db.usuarios.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Hice mi sp y lo he dejado así, no se si esta bien, no tengo mucho conocimiento :v

```
public JsonResult Lista() {
        return Json(db.SP_leerUsuario, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: En tu consulta tendrias que devolver ese rol, y ahi en vez del id pasarias el dato de tu ROL, igual si pudieras mostrar la consulta que esta devolviendo esos datos

Comment: ahí te muestro como esta mi json, también habia pensado en vez de llamar a toda la tabla así hacer una lista de los datos y ahí ver como retornar los campos que deseo pero no se como hacer esa lista :v

Comment: Por que no usar un sp y llamar a ese sp y devolver la lista que necesitas?

Comment: es una buena idea, ya hice el sp con un select inner join pero a la hora de llamar el sp con mi json result no me muestra nada en la tabla, lo llamo de la misma manera que ves mi json ahí solo que el .ToList no me deja hacerlo?

Comment: Como estas tratando de llamar a tu sp?

Comment: ahí edite, no se si esta bien así o es de otra forma

Comment: Usas Entity? o no?

Comment: si estoy usando EF, y en el modelo.edmx ya me muestra el sp

Comment: using (var db = new SP_leerUsuario())
            {
                
                var Results = db.SP_leerUsuario();
                return null;
            }
Prueba a ver su result te devuelve el dato

Comment: me dice que tengo que crear una clase SP_leerUsuario, pero creo que lo e hecho mal, la verdad no entiendo como tengo que poner lo que tú me comentaste ya lo probe de varias formas pero igual me da error

Comment: Trata con 
var usuarios = db.SP_Usuario().ToList(), pon un punto de interrupción para ver que te devuelve eso

Comment: cada vez que pongo el SP_leerUsuario me dice que debo crear una clase porque no existe

Comment: Entity te debio de crear un result es esa clase verifica que este

Comment: me creo esto [public object SP_leerUsuario { get; set; }] en la clase de modelo.cs

Comment: Y tiene los datos de los sp que esperas recibir no?

Comment: pues en el sp que cree en la bd tiene todos los datos que necesito pero en ese objeto solamente me muestra eso

Comment: @EdgarVazquez lo solucione, no habia agregado bien el Result del sp, si pones la respuesta que solo creando un sp lo resuelvo te dejo el check de correcto

Comment: Claro esta bien amigo te lo pongo, saludos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola podrias crear un sp y ahi mapear los datos correctos asi cuando devuelvas tu consulta este ya tiene los datos que necesitas y al devolverlo a tu Javascript sera mas facil.

Saludos